# How to use the setState hook to overwrite the data in state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, setstate, use-state

I am working with the Cotext API in Next.js and need to know the best way to change the state in the below snippet of code. The expected functionality is that when the user presses submit in another form component, the getSearchInput function will take this value update the `SearchInput` state. This should happen eevrytime the user submits a new string in the input field and what I have so far works,

```
const getSearchInput = (string) => {
        setSearchInput(string);
    };
```

The issue is that im aware that its never a good idea to update state directly like this. But im not aware of how else I can remove the previous string and replace it with tge latest. If you are looking for the code of the full context component, you can find it below

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const SearchContext = createContext();

const SearchProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [ state, setstate ] = useState(null);
    const [ searchInput, setSearchInput ] = useState('');

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

            const getData = async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${searchInput}`);
                    setstate(response.data.results);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('error', error);
                }
            };

            getData();

            return () => {
                source.cancel();
            };
        },
        [ searchInput ]
    );

    const getSearchInput = (string) => {
        setSearchInput((prev) => string);
    };

    return <SearchContext.Provider value={{ state, getSearchInput, searchInput }}>{children}</SearchContext.Provider>;
};

export { SearchContext, SearchProvider };
```

Comment: Can you share with us why your current approach is never a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

actually, you're using it in the right way! you are using `setSearchInput` which is the only way to update the state.
changing state directly (or mutate it) means you change it in a way like this :

```
const getSearchInput = (string) => {
    searchInput=string;
};
```

you can read react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initalValue)
```

The state has an `initialValue` for the first render

the only way to update that state which is defined by useState is to use the second element in the returned list usually starts with the `set` keyword as a convention, cause it is a setter

so to update that state you must use setState here
`setState` function can accept both function and a single value
if it is the function it will receive the very last state, and if it is a value it will just override the state with a new value

```
setState(prevState => newState)
setState(newState)
```

if you search for refactoring tips or something, I guess you can remove the `getSearchInput` declaration and pass setState with a different name as your context value e.g.

```
return (
  <SearchContext.Provider 
    value={{ 
           state, 
           getSearchInput: setSearchInput, 
           searchInput 
    }}
   >
    {children}
  </SearchContext.Provider>
);
```

Also for using a Context as a state manager tool in react it is highly recommended to use useReducer instead and pass dispatch and state in two different context level

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialArg, init)

return (
  <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
    <DispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      {children}
    </DispatchContext.Provider>
  </StateContext.Provider>
)
```

**References**
[useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)
[application state management with react](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/application-state-management-with-react)